# Passing the input of a client to a class connected to the server class

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

I am working on a client server application to take in a string input from the user, and output how many times that sequence was found in a file. The class that reads the file and counts the sequence is a separate class that I am trying to connect to the server class, so the input from the user is passed to the server, which passes it to that class, and then returns the output to the client...but I don't know how, please help!

**Client Class**

```
public class Client extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;
    private Socket connection;


    //constructor
    public Client(String host) {
        super("Client ...");
        serverIP = host;
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                });
        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(400,150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //connect to server
    public void startRunning() {
        try {
            connectToServer();
            setupStreams();
            whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException) {
            showMessage("Client terminated connection\n");
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            closeEverything();
        }
    }

    //connecting to the server for reals
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Trying to connect....");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
        showMessage("Finally connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    //setting up to transmit information
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n DNA searching is now live \n");
    }

    //private void whileChatting
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        ableToType(true);

        do{
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                showMessage("\n I do not recognize your input\n");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("SERVER-END"));
    }

    //Time to close the streams, and sockets
    private void closeEverything(){
        showMessage("\n Closing connection...");
        ableToType(false);
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Communicate with the server\
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " +message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\nCLIENT - "+message);
    }catch(IOException ioException) {
        chatWindow.append("\n Error string not sent.."); 
        } 
    }

    //update display
    private void showMessage(final String m) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chatWindow.append(m);
                    }
                }

        );
    }

    //Allow user search for chromosomes

    private void ableToType (final boolean tof) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        userText.setEditable(tof);
                    }
                }

        );

    }
}
```

**Server Class**

```
public class Server extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;
    GenomeSearcher Gs = new GenomeSearcher();
    String findSequence, chromosome;

    //constructor

    public Server() {
        super("DNA Strands Search Engine");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //pass the genetic code function here!
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");
                //end user text here



            }

        });    //end action listener

        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
        setSize(400, 150);
        setVisible(true);


        userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runSearcher();
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        }


        );


    }//end server

    public void runSearcher() {
        Gs.countSequence(findSequence, chromosome);
    }

        //set up and run server
        public void startRunning() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        waitForConnection();
                        setupStreams();
                        whileChatting(); //might not need this
                    }catch(EOFException eofException) {
                        showMessage("\n Server closed the connection...");
                    }finally {
                        closeEverything();
                    }
                }//end while
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //wait for connection, display connection

        public void waitForConnection()throws IOException {
            showMessage("Waiting for connection...\n");
            connection = server.accept();
            showMessage("Now connected to " +connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }

        //stream to send and receive info
        public void setupStreams()throws IOException{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            showMessage("\n Connection fully established \n");

        }

        //during strand searching

        public void whileChatting()throws IOException {
            String message = "You are now connected";
            sendMessage(message);
            ableToType(true);

            do {
                //send and receive info

                try {
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    showMessage("\n" +message);
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                    showMessage("\nUser info is invalid..");
                }
            }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
        }

        //close all streams and sockets
        public void closeEverything() {
            showMessage("\n Closing connection..\n");
            ableToType(false);
            try {
                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //send message to client
        public void sendMessage(String message) {
            try {
                output.writeObject("SERVER - "+  message);
                output.writeObject("SERVER - "+ count);                                             //output dna result here
                output.flush();
                showMessage("\n SERVER - "+message);//shows history of user input....might not need
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                chatWindow.append("\n Your message is invalid");
            }
        }

        //update chat window
        public void showMessage(final String text) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chatWindow.append(text);
                    }
                }
                    );      

            }//end showMessage

        //let the user type

        public void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        userText.setEditable(tof);
                    }
                }
                    );  
        }
}
```

**Genome Searcher Class**

```
public class GenomeSearcher {

    //read from file
    public void readFile()throws Exception {
    Server s = new Server();
    File chromosome = new File("chr1.fa");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (chromosome));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String st;
    while((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(st);
    }//end while


    //time to count how many times a sequence appears


    }


    public int countSequence(String findSequence, String chromosome) {
        int count = 0;
        String result;

        List<Integer> Search = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> searchOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
        Server s = new Server();

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(chromosome);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (in));
            String strLine;

            while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int startIndex = strLine.indexOf(findSequence);
                while (startIndex != -1){
                    count++;
                    startIndex = chromosome.indexOf(findSequence, startIndex +findSequence.length());
                }
            }
            in.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
        s.showMessage("Nothing");
        }

        //Search.add(count);

    //  String result = Integer.toString(count);

        for(Integer i: Search) {
            searchOutput.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for(String sw: searchOutput) {
            sb.append(sw);
            sb.append(" ");
        }

        String str;
        str = sb.toString(); 

        s.showMessage(str);

        for (String sp : searchOutput)
          {               
               System.out.println(sp);      
          }

        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }   



}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you expect? What happens actually? Is there any exception? Can you show the stack trace in that case? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the minimal is important). Try to reduce your code to something that explains your problem but is easy to understand and not too much.

Comment: Hey there, my bad for the long post...this is my first time using this site...the code is supposed to take in a DNA strand the user inputs (like ATATACG) and output how many times that sequence appears. I've done the counting part (Genome Searcher), but I don't know how to pass it into the server class so the input from the client goes into the Genome Searcher class through the server, and the info returned back to the client

Comment: Just send it through an `OutputStream` on one side of the socket and read it using an `InputStream` on the other side.

Comment: ```Output Stream``` on the server class and ```Input Stream``` on the Genome Searcher class?

Comment: If you want to aend data from the client to the server, the client needs to write it in the `OutputStream` so that the server can read it from the `InputStream`. If the server should send something to the client, the server must write to the `OutputStream` so thst the client is able to read it from the `InputStream`. If you need both, both need to write and read(read and write on the other side). But take care of deadlocks :)

Comment: Okay now, how do I print out the array list, or the ```count``` value in the ```countSequence``` class through the ```Output Stream``` in the server class?

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response too!

Answer (score 0):

You can write data to an `OutputStream` and read it from an `InputStream`.

If you want to send data from the client to the server, the client needs to write it in the `OutputStream` so that the server can read it from the `InputStream`.

If the server should send something to the client, the server must write to the `OutputStream` so thst the client is able to read it from the `InputStream`. If you need both, both need to write and read(read and write on the other side).

If you want to send an `ArrayList` of serializable objects(`String`s are serializable) from the client to the server, you can just write it (on the client side) using `output.writeObject(theArrayList);` and receive it (on the server side) using `ArrayList<String> theList=(ArrayList<String>)input.readObject();`(as you are using Object streams.

If you want to transmit non-object data(for example `int`s), you can use other `read` and `write` methods the streams provide.

But if both the server and client are reading at the same time and no one has written anything that has not yet been read, you will expearience a `Deadlock`. This means that both processes wait for each other and will not wake up as they need the other process(that is sleeping) to make them wake up.

Comment: I want to send the values of the array list in the Genome searcher class, to the client.

Comment: The whole array list or just some values?

Comment: ```List<String> searchOutput = new ArrayList<String>();``` this is the array I am talking about

Comment: As I stated: use `output.writeObject(searchOutput);` to send it and receive it using `List<String> searchOutput=(List<String>)input.readObject();`

Comment: The whole array list

Comment: In that case: as I said

Comment: will I place ```List<String> searchOutput=(List<String>)input.readObject();``` in the client class, or the server class?

Comment: Do you want to send it from the client to the server or in the opposite direction?

Comment: If you want to send it **from** the **server** **to** the **client**, you need to write the `readObject` code on the **client** side.

Comment: Okay I think I am starting to understand now, if i put the ```output.writeObject(searchOutput);``` in the server section, how would I call in the array list, from the Genome searcher class to the server class? since it's there, before the output to the client?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: how can I sort of pass the ```searchOutput``` array in the server class? so I can use ```output.writeObject(searchOutput);``` to output to the client

Comment: The ```searchOutput``` array is in the Genome Searcher class

Comment: Just create a new method in that class, for example `public void sendOutput(List<String> searchOutput){output.writeObject(searchOutput);}`

Comment: By the way, an array is not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I am getting the error that ```.writeObject``` is not applicable for the arguments void

Comment: when I try to put it in the server class

Comment: You need to pass the `ArrayList` to `writeObject`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Thanks again for helping

Comment: Is is possible to use a variable in the genomeSearcher class in the server class?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Just add the variable setter in that class and call it from the other class. If you don't know how to do that, take a look at java/OOP basics before even thinking about socket programming.